# Setting default arguments for Maven

Tags: java, maven

Currently, to run my project, I have to run in terminal something like this:

```
mvn clean install -DappURL=https://abcxyz.apk -DdefaultSuiteFiles=test.xml
```

I have to pass 2 arguments `appURL` and `defaultSuiteFiles` for my project to run (those are for CI flow on the cloud), but it really inconvenient when debugging in local enviroment.

Is there a way to set default values in the pom file for these 2 arguments, if I don't specify them in the terminal run command? So I can run with just `mvn clean install`, or running debug in Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to set a suite file? Why not using the defaults of Maven and run tests based on naming conventions?